# How to add @AllureId annotation to tests in source code using cli?

Tags: java, junit5, allure

Our application is spring boot based project written with kotlin. There is great plugin for JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA for Allure support. The plugin provide a possibility to generate test reports, upload them to Allure TestOps and link tests from source code to test launch (tree of all tests) in Allure TestOps. Linking is achieved through adding @AllureId annotation to tests in source code.

My goal is automate this process inside build pipelines. Allure has allurectl tool which allows to upload test reports to Allure TestOps. But as far as I concerned it doesn't have a feature to assign @AllureId annotations.

Is there any option to assign @AllureId to tests from source code using command line?

Answer (score 1):

You are generally right - allurectl does not have this feature. It is supported in the Allure IDEA plugin only.

The reason is that automated test-case linking feature in the plugin is implemented via the IntelliJ engine, so we'd have to write our own engine for the allurectl to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I've find out that adding a label's node with name "as_id" to generated json report works as a way to set allureId. Tested with upload to Allure TestOps, it works.

Some details are here and in related PR:https://github.com/Tinkoff/Allure.XUnit/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is the AllureID must exist in Allure TestOps. The link between your code and test case created in Allure TestOps is method's full signature displayed on your test case panel in Allure TestOps.
The standard designed workflow is described here: https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/ecosystem/ide-plugins/#link-tests-in-ide-to-tests-cases-in-allure-testops-via-allureid
Generally, you need to assign AllureID either when you create a new test in Jetbrains' IDE (made automatically) or if you are altering something in the existing test (name of the package, class name, method's name)/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34287455)

Comment: this is the essence: you need to assign AllureID either when you create a new test in Jetbrains' IDE (made automatically) or if you are altering something in the existing test (name of the package, class name, method's name)